# For some reason my mysql wont insert

Tags: php, mysql

I've been looking at this for hours, and I can't find the problem as to why my sql insert won't work.

```
$body = "link test - 3!!!";
$userid = 1;
$cat_id = 3;
$user_url = "http://www.pizza.com";
$body = mysql_real_escape_string($body);

$sql = "insert into posts (userid, body, stamp, cat_id, link) values ($userid,$body,now(),$cat_id,$user_url)";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Nice edit, @Fred -ii- :)

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/283366)

Comment: Thanks @GreenAsJade --- One of my [specialties](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/223/copy-editor?userid=1415724) ;-)

Comment: don't look at it for hours, add error checking.

Comment: @Dagon, +1 to your comment, also the user could examine the string value of `$sql`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$body` and `$user_url` are string but you didn't quote .

```
$sql = "insert into posts (userid, body, stamp, cat_id, link) values ($userid,'$body',now(),$cat_id,'$user_url')";
```

and quote any other fields that need it.

Comment: Maybe an added note to quote the ones that "could" be strings? We don't know if `userid` and `cat_id` are VARCHAR or INT. Just saying. We don't know what the OP's schema is.

Comment: heres my db:  id int(11)   
user_id int(11)   
body varchar(140)
stamp datetime   
cat_id tinyint(1)
links varchar(500)

Comment: Then, what Musa posted should suffice. @user3195457

Answer (score 0):

You also need to escape special characters in $body to avoid future problems.

```
$sql = "insert into posts (userid, body, stamp, cat_id, link) values ($userid, '".mysql_real_escape_string($body)."', '".now()."', $cat_id, '$user_url')";
```